# Show a child element on hover, and hide when not hovering

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple `span` elements having the same `prod_desc` class and they are hidden by default. Now I am showing on hover, however, the problem is that all of them shows up!

I want only the element to show on which currently I am hovering. I think I need to use this but I could not figure out how.

Parent element :

```
    <div id="results" style="width: 600px;"></div>
```

Rendering these element using AJAX into results id element.

```
<div class="prod" style="position: relative;width: 265px;border: 1px solid black;float: left;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
<img src="'.$_product->getImageUrl().'"/>
<span class="prod_desc" style="position: absolute;display:none;">Hello I am descripton span block
</span>        
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("div#results").hover(function(){
    jQuery("span.prod_desc").show();
},function(){
    jQuery("span.prod_desc").hide();
});
```

I have also tried this, but it did not work:

```
jQuery("div#results").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find("span.prod_desc").show();
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find("span.prod_desc").hide();
});
```

Comment: OMG now why down voting?

Comment: Can you post some HTML markup?

Comment: I have edited and included html

Comment: I'd try the CSS rule and comment your code.  It makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
if(jQuery('.prod').length != 0) {
    jQuery(".prod").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").hide();
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeIn();
},function(){        
jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeOut(); 

jQuery(this).find(".prod_title_wrap").show();
jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").show();
});
```

}

I was putting check before the ajax call comes back. So using this I am waiting for it to finish and then implementing further checks. Thanks all for you for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want only the element to show on which currently I am hovering.

and then just attach hover function to element you want.

```
jQuery("span.prod_desc").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).show();
     },function(){
   jQuery(this).hide();
 });
```

**BUT**

> they are hidden by default.

how do you hovering them ??

Comment: I am confuse, you said that 'they are hidden by default' how do you hovering them ?? can you create fiddle please??

Comment: By default I mean to say, upon ajax rendering I have set the span to display none. So now When I hover the parent element results I want the span to show. Which is showing but all of the spans are showing

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS.  I believe the issue may be how the elements are being placed on the page and how jQuery events work.  Try this with CSS rules and see how that works.

```
#results .prod_desc {
  display: none;
}

#results:hover .prod_desc {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to show prod_desc .prod is already showing. .prod is parent of prod_desc class

Comment: Then change it from .prod to .prod_desc

Comment: Edited answer for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

If these are dynamically added, try this

```
jQuery(document).on('hover', '#results', function () {
    jQuery("span.prod_desc").show();
}, function(){
    jQuery("span.prod_desc").hide();
});
```